# Requirejs and nested modules

Tags: requirejs, nested

I have the following logic using pnotify.js:

```
    //File notification.js
define(['require','pnotify' ],
        function(require,PNotify){

           require( [ 'pnotify.nonblock', 'pnotify.desktop' ],function(){
               PNotify.desktop.permission();
           });
        });
```

and in another file
//File notification2.js

```
define(['notification' ],
    function(Notification){
            return function(msg){
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Desktop Notice',
                    text: msg,
                    desktop: {
                        desktop: true
                    },
                    nonblock: {
                        nonblock: true
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

This is working fine, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in only one file?
I am calling my function like this:

```
define([
    'notification2'
], function(Notification){

//some code
  var notif = Notification("hello");
//some code
```

Comment: Why did you break it into two modules in the first place?

Comment: Well when I did all in like this:
`define(['require','pnotify' ],
        function(require,PNotify){

           require( [ 'pnotify.nonblock', 'pnotify.desktop' ],function(){
               PNotify.desktop.permission();
return function(msg){
                new PNotify({
                    title: 'Desktop Notice',
                    text: msg,
                    desktop: {
                        desktop: true
                    },
                    nonblock: {
                        nonblock: true
                    }
                });
            }
           });`

        });

Comment: It didn t work, so I tried separing this and it worked.